# QueryTable not being created

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to call information from Yahoo Finance but I keep on getting an error saying the url I am trying to use is not giving any information. However when I manually put the url in I get the data and when I use that url in an .iqy file it works. I got the following vba code when I recorded a macro, but the macro doesn't run.

```
Sub GetandArrangeData()
'
' GetandArrangeData Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+b
'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=1112.HK&d=4&e=15&f=2015&g=d&a=5&b=27&c=2000&ignore=.csv" _
        , Destination:=Range("C3"))
        .PostText = "MSN MoneyCentral Stock Quotes_1"
        .Name = False
        .FieldNames = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = 1
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
        .SaveData = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .UseListObject = False
    End With
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 5), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 9), _
        Array(7, 9))
    Columns("D:F").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

I get the following error each time :

[image]

For some reason the ampersands in the url vanish, no idea why.

Comment: I'm not certain, thus not an answer, but a couple of possibilities: 1) try doubling the `&` to `&&`, 2) try escaping the `&` with `\&`, 3) try replacing `&` with `" & chr(38) & "`. Again, just some guesses. Which line is it failing on?

Comment: Thanks! the double ampersand works, but I found another problem which was that i used URL instead of TEXT, as the address is a csv file. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, copying the answer from a comment to here:

Replace the `&`s in the URL string with `&&`s.